# Effective usage of dm_db_missing_index_details

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

How can i effectively use the **dm_db_missing_index_details** of SQL SERVER databases. Should i need to create all the missing indexes detailed in the table or not and what does **equality_columns** and **inequality_columns** means.
How can i utilize the **equality_columns** ,**inequality_columns** and **included columns** while creating an index out of it (non clustered index).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you don't  need to create all the index suggested by dm_db_missing_index_details    But it worths to pay attention and check for a possible performance improvement

Equality columns are fields to use for search operations with EQUAL "=" operator

Inequality columns are fields that better suit for range comparisons like BETWEEN or LESS or GREATER THAN etc.

According to your comment following statement can be executed to create a non-clustered index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [INDEXNAME] ON [TABLENAME] (
    [EQUALITYCOLUMNNAME], 
    [INEQUALITYCOLUMNNAME]
) 
INCLUDE (
    [INCLUDECOLUMN]
);
```

Although I added the equality columns and inequality columns in a single index definition, you can think of creating seperate indexes

As a rule, most selective and equality columns should be defined at the begining of the index columns list. Inequality columns follow equality columns in Create Index statement's field list

Please refer to [create index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql) statement description

Comment: Hi Jesalcv, do you have a screenshot of the rows on dm_db_missing_index_details view for the table you want to create index on